# How shall I place a icon(Material Icon) and text in a same line in the vertical menu bar

Tags: html, css, navigation, icons

How do I place an icon (Material Icon) and text in the same line in the vertical menu bar. I don't want to use a table, as I won't be able to hover over both simultaneously [You can see only one of them is selected when hovering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m88hx.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"        rel="stylesheet">

<style>
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 200px;
background-color: #5A7A88;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: lightgrey;
padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}


li a:hover {
background-color: #7D8D96;
color: white;
}


.menu {
 width: 240px;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 background:#5A7A88;
 left:0px;
 transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  }

 .menu-icon {
 padding:10px 20px;
 background:#5A7A88;
 color:#987D3E;
 cursor:pointer;
 float:right;
 margin-top:4px;
 border-radius:5px;
 }

 #menuToggle {
 display:inline;
 }

 #menuToggle:checked  ~ .menu {
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>


 <nav class="menu">
 <ul>
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td><li><a class="material-icons">add</a></li></td>

 <td><li><a href="#home">APPLICATION INFO</a></li></td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><li><a class="material-icons">add</a></li></td>

 <td><li><a href="#home">DEVICE INFO</a></li></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><li><a class="material-icons">add</a></li></td>

 <td><li><a href="#home">PROCESS LIST</a></li></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><li><a class="material-icons">add</a></li></td>

 <td><li><a href="#home">REMOTE CONTROL HISTORY</a></li></td>
 </tr>





  <td><li><a class="material-icons">add</a></li></td>


 </table>
 </ul>
 </nav>


 </body>
 </html>
```

[image]

Comment: HI now you can used jquery ui accordian

Comment: Please show us some code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: How can I paste my code here, its too long for me to paste here.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li .material-icons, ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.material-icons {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-right: 7px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
  <li>
    <i class="material-icons">3d_rotation</i>
    <a href="#">Link One</a>
  </li>
</ul>
  </body>
```

I am not too sure what you are expecting, but you could easily do it, check the snippet. Make sure you use vertical-align to the icon and link in the list.

Comment: It looks like you have placed an image in the span class, but I would like to include material design icons like <i class="material-icons">face</i> very close to the text. I also wanted the icon to appear bigger, when the menu bar contracts and vice versa. Most importantly, I wanted to implement this without bootstrap.

Comment: Just replace .icons with .material-icons or your class, and remove the image.

Comment: After replacing the code to  <span class="material-icons"><i class="material-icons">face</i></span>I am getting output as "face" in italics

Comment: I dont know what library you are using. But whatever you are doing is wrong. If you don't show the code it is really hard to explain, especially because you are  just starting out.

Comment: Looks like I have learnt how to post a code after a very demanding reply.

Comment: I have updated the snippet to exactly match your code. You can copy paste it and you're set to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
  rel="stylesheet">
<style>
 body {
margin: 0;
}

 ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 25%;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 position: fixed;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 }

li a {
display: block;
color: #000;
padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #555;
color: white;
}

ul li .material-icons, ul li a {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.material-icons {
font-size: 20px;
margin-right: 7px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
<li>
<a href="#"><i class="material-icons">3d_rotation</i>Link One</a>
<a href="#"><i class="material-icons">3d_rotation</i>Link One</a>
<a href="#"><i class="material-icons">3d_rotation</i>Link One</a>
<a href="#"><i class="material-icons">3d_rotation</i>Link One</a>
</li>
</ul>

<div style="margin-left:25%;padding:1px 16px;height:1000px;">

 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: @Vividua Elsaphe, Try running this code and see the result appears